# Why was Ethan Hunt in a Russian prison at the start of Ghost Protocol?

Tags: plot-explanation, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-ghost-protocol

As the title says I’m wondering if I missed something. Why was Ethan Hunt in a Russian prison at the start of *Mission: Impossible - Ghost Protocol*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's explained at the very end of the movie, when he assigns new mission, and he talks to Brandt (who refuses the phone). He says he was sentenced to prison

> for killing serbians after they allegedly killed his wife. It was just a setup as Julia is still alive. But this allowed him to protect her and then go undercover. Going to prison was a sacrifice he was willing to make.

The [full script](https://www.scripts.com/script-pdf/13880), pages 29/30.

You have the ending scene with Hunt and Brandt, starting at 2:50

Comment: How can that be the full script when it doesn't even show who's speaking?

Comment: @Kyralessa: actually, I couldn't find a better written piece, close to the final play of the movie.

Comment: @Kyralessa: added the ending scene so it can be read with subtiles too.

Comment: @Kyralessa it's not any kind of script, it's a subtitle rip.